# How can i make that the lines in richTextBox1 will start from the right to the left?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Some lines already start from the right since they are long. But in general all line are stick to the left.
I want to allign them to the right.

This is how i assign the text to the richTextBox:

```
combindedString = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, ListsExtractions.myList);
richTextBox1.Text = combindedString;
```

myList is `List<string>`
And myList formatted like this:

```
Index 0: text
Index 1: date&time
Index 2: link
Index 3: empty/space
```

Then again index 4: text index 5: dateTime and so on. 
I just want it to start/allign from the right.

Comment: __All__ formatting in a RTB is done by __first making a selection__ and then applying the format to it: richTextBox1.SelectAll();
            richTextBox1.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the documentation on `SelectionAlignment` property:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionalignment%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Use the above (in your scenario) like so:

```
richTextBox1.SelectAll();
richTextBox1.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
```